# Javascript - passing multiple variables when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to pass variables when a user clicks a button of a form, to a route (node.js)

The data i want to be passed, are the input fields of a form and the information from a radio button.

However, i want one extra string to be passed that the corresponding route will have access to.

```
var modelName = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>; // get the data from routes.js, containing the model name
modelName = "../myData/" + modelName; // make the filename a (directory + filename)
```

So, to sum up. That route will have access to a string, that when the user clicks a button of a form, i want that string, along with the info from the radio and the text input of the form to be passed to another route.

Is this possible to pass all the three different variables?

Comment: You can use js to make the request for you using axios, fetch, $.post, or some other API. Or, an easier option would be to add the additional string data you want to send in a `<input type="hidden" />` field, which will not appear on your form but will still get posted

Comment: I like the hidden option, this is  what i will do, thanks! The form can send the input field, the hidden input field, but what about the radio box value?

Comment: The selected radio button should be sent when you submit the form and available in the request’s body. You’ll just need to ensure that the radio buttons on your form have `name` attributes and are within your form

Comment: Thank you! So a single form can contain a radio, an input field, and a hidden input field. And when the button is pressed, the values from all three of them will be sent to the target route, is this correct?

Comment: yeah, exactly. The input fields must have their own name attributes though (the radio buttons can have the same ones though). Then on the server side you can access the data of each input field by using the name attributes you specified (using request.body.<name of field>). You need to make sure you’re using something like body-parser with your express app to parse the form data sent to your server though.